# When websocket connected to server via domen, Web socket status finished, if connected via ip addres it works

Tags: spring, websocket, sockjs

Spring boot application and used Spring web socket with Stomp. Is there anyone who faced to this problem?

My socket config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

And connected with ip address: [image: it connected successfully]

and if I try with domen: [image: not ok]

Comment: Please add the code to your question, and also explain what the problem is.